# writing to subdir - handling images

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

We are redirecting from a root domain to a subdirectory (`/test`) invisibly with Apache's `mod_rewrite`. We have WordPress installed on `/test`.

I am using the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

This works without issues, which is great! So my question is why are things like images not falling over with this rule. Surely requests like `/test/img.jpg` should be rewritten to `/test/test/img.jpg` (and thus return a 404) but they aren't? Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you have a `/test/.htaccess` as well.